# Not receiving touch event data in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, touch, dom-events

I am trying to do something fairly simple using Ionic framework.

```
<form>
<div class="list">
  <div>
    <img ng-src="some_image_source"></img>  
  </div>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="task.title">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="padding">
  <button on-touch="beginInterest(event)" class="button button-block button-positive">Create Task</button>
</div>
```

I want to capture the event object and associated data from this touch event in beginInterest function which is defined in my controller like so

```
  $scope.beginInterest = function (event) {
    // But there is no event object here! It's undefined.

  }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do `ng-touch="beginInterest($event)"` and you need to load `angular-touch.js` and have `ngTouch` on your app dependencies (e.g. `angular.module('myApp',['ngTouch'])`. documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: I want to achieve this through Ionic's on-touch directive. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTouch/

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `type="submit"`

```
<button on-touch="beginInterest()" class="button button-block button-positive">Create Task</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help. I have updated form's html above. Let me know if you got something else.